# Java code - consistent measurements across hardware?

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

Can anyone suggest a tool to measure efficiency of Java code, that's able to give identical results across machines (for the same code, same JVM versions)?

Idea is to compare code execution - but not to measure execution time as this will vary across different hardware. So perhaps to report "execution steps" or "units of work" or something similar.

Comment: What is your goal in doing that?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about big O notation and getting that for an entire system will not be possible, you will be able to figure it out for particular code paths though. That been said, it should be easy to calculate just by reading through the code.

Comment: If you're using the same code on every platform you're not measuring the efficiency of the code but some attribute(s) of the platform.  The efficiency of a code is a property of the code and does not vary when run on a different platform.

Comment: Have a team developing speed-critical code, and want to measure and compare performance of variations of solutions. I could benchmark the different solutions on a test rig - but am looking to compare 'speed' of code on developer machines themselves.

Comment: if you want accurate timing you need to test on the same hardware and the production machine.  Testing on anything else with be a good guide, but even if you use the same hardware, you will have trouble creating realistic tests.  BTW when you measure a system, you alter its behaviour, so you want to sample as little information as possible.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - same code on different platforms is not measuring efficiency - agreed. Intention is to find some platform-independent way of measuring speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Java Mission Control](http://download.oracle.com/technology/products/missioncontrol/updatesites/base/5.2.0/eclipse/).